# Maria DB - Help on Index

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

I have below query

```
Select main.display_column, lookup.lookup_column from
main
inner join lookup on main.main_column = lookup.lookup_column
where main.another_column = 123;
```

Is it enough to create index on
main.another_column and lookup.lookup_column

or index on main.main_column is also required to increase the performance?

Comment: I think `main.another_column` and `lookup.lookup_column` should do the work.

Answer (score 1):

No, an index on main.main_column isn't needed and wouldn't be used.

Set all three indexes and then do `explain select rest-of-your-query`; it will show only the two indexes being used.

If you had something like this:

```
select main.display_column, lookup.lookup_column
from main
inner join lookup on main.main_column = lookup.lookup_column
where main.another_column >= 123
order by lookup.primarykey
```

the optimizer might choose to reverse the join and use the index on main.main_column in order to have the records already in correct order, but in your straightforward case that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thanks, I believe the same but unable to find any documentation for the same, would you share any MariaDB documentation link if manage to find. Need it to support my point

Comment: set all three indexes and then do `explain select rest-of-your-query`; it will show only the two indexes being used.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked, these are the optimal Indexes:

```
main:    INDEX(another_column)   -- takes care of the WHERE
lookup:  INDEX(lookup_column)    -- takes care of the JOIN
```

Optionally (for possibly a little more speed):

```
main:  INDEX(another_column, main_column, display_column)  -- "covering"
```